# How to display application icon in menubar even application is quit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My application shows a icon in the menu bar but when the application is quit the icon goes off from the menu bar.

Do we have a way to code such that application always remian in the menu bar even it is quit.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Menubar application for Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac)

Comment: I already implemented a Menubar icon but as soon as i quit my application its disappearing from the menu bar. I want to know how enable it always even though i quit.

Comment: You can't do that and it doesn't make much sense. What would the icon do if the application has quit? If the user quits your menubar app, they expect that to make the icon go away. That's why they quit it. If the icon shouldn't go away, then don't quit the app (but if you prevent the user from doing that, expect them to be angry).

Comment: Thanks Ken. But i want to make such as anti virus icon which always remain in the menubar even though application is not present in the dock.

Comment: If you don't want the app's icon present in the Dock, you would typically make it a UI element (set `LSUIElement` in its Info.plist file). If you want it to sometimes have a Dock icon and sometimes not, I recommend that you split it into separate, inter-operating pieces: a UI element that lives in the menubar and a separate normal app that shows up in the Dock. In OS X 10.9 and later, you can use `-[NSApplication setActivationPolicy:]` to switch back and forth between a UI element and a regular app. (The method docs say you can't, but the release notes document the new feature.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can definitely switch an app to background (Accessory) mode and back again.  Semantically, the application never quits.

The basic idea is to use the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol to switch back and forth between accessory and regular app modes.  There are already methods to cancel quit, catch all windows being closed, and to handle the user trying to launch your app even if it's still running.  So put it all together, and you get the code below.

I left in code here showing how to load and unload the main GUI controlled by the `NSWindowController` `self.wincon` where self is the application delegate object. It loads and controls a separate `MainWindow.xib`.   If you don't have a window other than the mainmenu, it might be unnecessary.

I also have a user preference that needs to be set to enable all of this behavior.  By default, it will really, really quit.

I have nothing in `MainMenu.xib` but the menu-- switching to accessory mode will mean the menu is not displayed.

```
// Helper to close main window and switch to accessory mode
- (void) switchToBackgroundMode
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Need to check loaded to prevent closing a closed window and
        //  triggering a second call to applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed
        if ([self.wincon isWindowLoaded]) [self.wincon close];
        self.wincon = nil;
    }

    // Hide the menu and dock icon
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
}

#pragma mark Application Delegate Methods

// Called with a CMD-Q
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    // Cancel terminate if pref set
    if ([MyPreferencesController runInBackground])
    {
        [self switchToBackgroundMode];
        return NSTerminateCancel;
    } 
    return NSTerminateNow;
}

// Called when all windows closed
- (BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    if ([MYPreferencesController runInBackground]) {
        // This check is necessary to avoid calling switchToBGmode twice on a quit
        if (![NSApp activationPolicy] == NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory)
            [self switchToBackgroundMode];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

// Called if the app is in accessory mode and the user activates it through the dock or by
//   clicking a userNotification or trying to open the app
- (BOOL) applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)sender hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (!self.wincon) {
        self.wincon = [[MYMainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
    }

    // This ensures that the dock icon comes back
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

    // Show the window
    [self.wincon showWindow:NSApp];
    [self.wincon.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
    return YES;
}
```

Notes added 10/6/2016 since this has gotten some traction:

There is an [older answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948539/cocoa-go-to-foreground-background-programmatically/12981068#12981068).  It has a good discussion of the history of the changes but lacks sample code.

Finally, this answer and question entirely lacked the `LSUIElement` keyword, which was a historical OSX plist setting for apps of this type.  As described in the answer above and [this more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327597/why-can-setpresentationoptions-and-lsuielement-not-be-used-together/30341048#30341048), ***`LSUIElement` should be considered deprecated***.  If you have found an old blog post mentioning it, hopefully you have found more recent code samples that recommend not using it at all.

Comment: Thanks Steve. the code helps to implement the required functionality.

Comment: simply B R I L L I A N T! Thanks.