# Start Mac app on startup programmatically

Tags: macos, launchd

I have developed a Mac app which I want to start as soon as the Mac is started. How can I achieve this functionality programmatically?

I know about launchd, but can't find a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution
Thanks**

```
- (void)enableLoginItemWithLoginItemsReference:(LSSharedFileListRef)theLoginItemsRefs ForPath:(NSString *)appPath  {
    // We call LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL to insert the item at the bottom of Login Items list.

    CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appPath];
    LSSharedFileListItemRef item = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(theLoginItemsRefs, kLSSharedFileListItemLast, NULL, NULL, url, NULL, NULL);
    if (item)
        CFRelease(item);
}


- (void)disableLoginItemWithLoginItems {
    UInt32 seedValue;
    CFURLRef thePath = NULL;

    NSString * appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    // Create a reference to the shared file list.
    LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);


    // We're going to grab the contents of the shared file list (LSSharedFileListItemRef objects)
    // and pop it in an array so we can iterate through it to find our item.
    CFArrayRef loginItemsArray = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems, &seedValue);
    for (id item in (__bridge NSArray *)loginItemsArray) {
        LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)item;
        if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, 0, (CFURLRef*) &thePath, NULL) == noErr) {
            if ([[(__bridge NSURL *)thePath path] hasPrefix:appPath]) {
                LSSharedFileListItemRemove(loginItems, itemRef); // Deleting the item
            }
            // Docs for LSSharedFileListItemResolve say we're responsible
            // for releasing the CFURLRef that is returned
            if (thePath != NULL) CFRelease(thePath);
        }
    }
    if (loginItemsArray != NULL) CFRelease(loginItems);
}



- (BOOL)loginItemExistsWithLoginItemReference:(LSSharedFileListRef)theLoginItemsRefs ForPath:(NSString *)appPath {
    BOOL found = NO;
    UInt32 seedValue;
    CFURLRef thePath = NULL;

    // We're going to grab the contents of the shared file list (LSSharedFileListItemRef objects)
    // and pop it in an array so we can iterate through it to find our item.
    CFArrayRef loginItemsArray = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(theLoginItemsRefs, &seedValue);
    for (id item in (__bridge NSArray *)loginItemsArray) {
        LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)item;
        if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, 0, (CFURLRef*) &thePath, NULL) == noErr) {
            if ([[(__bridge NSURL *)thePath path] hasPrefix:appPath]) {
                found = YES;
                break;
            }
            // Docs for LSSharedFileListItemResolve say we're responsible
            // for releasing the CFURLRef that is returned
            if (thePath != NULL) CFRelease(thePath);
        }
    }
    if (loginItemsArray != NULL) CFRelease(loginItemsArray);

    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This code below was developed from an excellent blog post by Tim Schroeder: [The Launch At Login Sandbox Project](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/).**  Actually more or less borrowed completely from there-- it looks like I only ever had to change the log messages and strings in there, so it's pretty rock solid if I never screwed with it.

Where my opinion differs with that post is that *there should be no "helper" app*, even if you want the app to launch without a GUI at login.  It's unnecessary.  If you want your app to have a background mode that runs at login or when the use closes the GUI, you should switch the app to accessory mode as [detailed in my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088906/how-to-display-application-icon-in-menubar-even-application-is-quit/24094273#24094273)  You don't need to deal with subprojects and compiling separate executables.  Just have one.

Anyways, Tim's eminently useful code.  It uses a segmented control on a preferences panel to toggle the app on/off.   The segmentedControl value uses cocoa-bindings to bind the control value to NSUserDefaults, so all that's seen here is registering/unregistering the app as a login item, and error checking/alerting.

```
- (IBAction)toggleRunAtLogin:(NSSegmentedControl*)sender {
    NSLog(@"toggling run at login");
    NSUInteger clickedSegment = [sender selectedSegment];
    if (clickedSegment == 0) { // ON
        // Turn on launch at login
        NSLog(@"... to ON");
        if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled ((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.yourCo.yourApp", YES)) {
            NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"An error ocurred"
                                             defaultButton:@"OK"
                                           alternateButton:nil
                                               otherButton:nil
                                 informativeTextWithFormat:@"Couldn't add App to launch at login item list."];
            [alert runModal];
        }
    }
    if (clickedSegment == 1) { // OFF
        // Turn off launch at login
        NSLog(@"... to OFF");
        if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled ((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.yourCo.yourApp", NO)) {
            NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"An error ocurred"
                                             defaultButton:@"OK"
                                           alternateButton:nil
                                               otherButton:nil
                                 informativeTextWithFormat:@"Couldn't remove App from launch at login item list."];
            [alert runModal];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A great example of the implementation of this can be found at https://github.com/nfarina/feeds/blob/master/Feeds/LoginItems.m

```
#import "LoginItems.h"

@implementation LoginItems

// Copied from https://github.com/carpeaqua/Shared-File-List-Example

- (void)enableLoginItemWithLoginItemsReference:(LSSharedFileListRef )theLoginItemsRefs ForPath:(NSString *)appPath {
    // We call LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL to insert the item at the bottom of Login Items list.
CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appPath];
LSSharedFileListItemRef item = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(theLoginItemsRefs, kLSSharedFileListItemLast, NULL, NULL, url, NULL, NULL);        
if (item)
    CFRelease(item);
}

- (void)disableLoginItemWithLoginItemsReference:(LSSharedFileListRef )theLoginItemsRefs ForPath:(NSString *)appPath {
UInt32 seedValue;
CFURLRef thePath = NULL;
// We're going to grab the contents of the shared file list (LSSharedFileListItemRef objects)
// and pop it in an array so we can iterate through it to find our item.
CFArrayRef loginItemsArray = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(theLoginItemsRefs, &seedValue);
for (id item in (NSArray *)loginItemsArray) {       
    LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (LSSharedFileListItemRef)item;
    if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, 0, (CFURLRef*) &thePath, NULL) == noErr) {
        if ([[(NSURL *)thePath path] hasPrefix:appPath]) {
            LSSharedFileListItemRemove(theLoginItemsRefs, itemRef); // Deleting the item
        }
        // Docs for LSSharedFileListItemResolve say we're responsible
        // for releasing the CFURLRef that is returned
        if (thePath != NULL) CFRelease(thePath);
    }       
}
if (loginItemsArray != NULL) CFRelease(loginItemsArray);
}

- (BOOL)loginItemExistsWithLoginItemReference:(LSSharedFileListRef)theLoginItemsRefs ForPath:(NSString *)appPath {
BOOL found = NO;  
UInt32 seedValue;
CFURLRef thePath = NULL;

// We're going to grab the contents of the shared file list (LSSharedFileListItemRef objects)
// and pop it in an array so we can iterate through it to find our item.
CFArrayRef loginItemsArray = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(theLoginItemsRefs, &seedValue);
for (id item in (NSArray *)loginItemsArray) {    
    LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (LSSharedFileListItemRef)item;
    if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, 0, (CFURLRef*) &thePath, NULL) == noErr) {
        if ([[(NSURL *)thePath path] hasPrefix:appPath]) {
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
        // Docs for LSSharedFileListItemResolve say we're responsible
        // for releasing the CFURLRef that is returned
        if (thePath != NULL) CFRelease(thePath);
    }
}
if (loginItemsArray != NULL) CFRelease(loginItemsArray);

return found;
}

// Our code

+ (LoginItems *)userLoginItems {
    static LoginItems *userItems = nil;
    return userItems ?: (userItems = [LoginItems new]);
}

- (BOOL)currentAppLaunchesAtStartup {
    NSString * appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
    BOOL exists = [self loginItemExistsWithLoginItemReference:loginItems ForPath:appPath];
    CFRelease(loginItems);
    return exists;
}

- (void)setCurrentAppLaunchesAtStartup:(BOOL)currentAppLaunchesAtStartup {
    NSString * appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);

    if (loginItems) {
        if (!self.currentAppLaunchesAtStartup)
            [self enableLoginItemWithLoginItemsReference:loginItems ForPath:appPath];
        else
            [self disableLoginItemWithLoginItemsReference:loginItems ForPath:appPath];
        CFRelease(loginItems);
    }
}

@end
```