# Overriding close action in OSX

Tags: macos

How do I override the close button action to show a confirm dialog?
Would placing code in the app delegate's

```
applicationWillTerminate
```

be the correct place for such code?

I have an app using CloudKit.
It saves way too constantly, where it causes errors trying to save to iCloud.

So I'm trying to show a dialog to confirm if the user wants to sync before quitting.

Comment: [Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088906/how-to-display-application-icon-in-menubar-even-application-is-quit/24094273#24094273) about `applicationShouldTerminate` may help, but you sound like you'd want to keep the window open, which would require a NSWindowController method, likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to block a window from closing, the NSWindow's delegate is where it's at. Be it either the AppDelegate (which is the default for most Xcode templates) or an NSWindowController if that's how you presented your window. The method you want to implement from [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowShouldClose:) is `-windowShouldClose:` or `-windowWillClose:`. If you want to prevent the closing of the window, simply return `NO` from `-windowShouldClose:`.

If you want to stop the app from quitting, you should look into [NSApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationShouldTerminate:) and override `-applicationShouldTerminate:` and return `NSTerminateCancel` to prevent the app from terminating.

In short, the "should" methods allow you to prevent the action from occurring, the "will" methods are just saying that it will happen and you can deal with it.