# Why can setPresentationOptions and LSUIElement not be used together?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, nsapplication

Code:

```
[NSApp setPresentationOptions: NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar | NSApplicationPresentationHideDock];
```

It hides Dock and MenuBar OSX.

When I add key LSUIElement into my Info.plist file and rerun my code: Dock is hidden, but MenuBar doesn't hidden.

Why?
How to hide MenuBar after adding LSUIElement?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it should hide the main menu always and forever, *but* using `LSUIElement` in the plist is an older way of doing things than using both `setActivationPolicy` and `setPresentationOptions` so you might want to give `[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory]`  a shot instead.

The `LSUIElement` way of doing things didn't support changes at runtime.  You're mixing old and new.  Deprecate `LSUIElement` and use `setActivationPolicy` on OSX 10.9+.

There is lots of discussion along these lines.  [This is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948539/cocoa-go-to-foreground-background-programmatically/12981068#12981068).   I wrote an answer about how to switch to accessory mode when the user "quits" the app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088906/how-to-display-application-icon-in-menubar-even-application-is-quit) and that uses the runtime functionality which `LSUIElement` would break.  So don't use it.